# Using Python to find the difference between two columns of numbers from an excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file that I have imported into Python using pandas and it has two columns, purchase price and sales price. They are both number values. I want to use python to automatically do the math for me to find the difference between the two, in this case I want it to be Sales Price minus Purchase Price. Is it possible to write a script for this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# create new column named profit
df['profit'] = df['Sales Price'] - df['Purchase Price']
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Read the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

## Find the difference between the two columns

df['difference'] = df['column1'] - df['column2']

## Print the resulting DataFrame

print(df)

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also Stack Overflow's [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you will need to iterate over the columns you have pulled into pandas similar to the psuedo code below

```
import pandas as pd
file = "path/to/file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
mapped_sales_price = df['Sales Price'].values()
mapped_purchase_price = df['Purchase Price'].values()
profit = [x - y for x in mapped_sales_price for y in mapped_purchase_price]
print(profit)
```

From here you can easily create a new column in the pandas dataframe with the profit to see the profit per row, however if you are only interested in the total profit of the entire csv entries you have recorded then you can do something like this with the profit array (list)

```
total_profit = sum(int(i for i in profit))
```

this will convert any strings to integers , if you have floating point values then you would need something like this

```
import math
normalized_profit_values = list(map( float, profit))
total_profit = math.fsum(normalized_profit_values)
```